# Integrate New ASP.NET MVC App With Existing Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

We've got an existing ASP.NET web application that already uses a home-grown role based authentication system.  Each user has a role and that role is actually a fully realized class in itself.  It still boils down to a pretty standard set of roles (user, administrator, owner, etc).

Now we're starting up a new ASP.NET MVC project that uses the same core libraries including the existing users and roles.  I'd like to use the built in functionality for role based authorization like:

```
[Authorize(Roles="administrator")]
```

We've already modified the default login behavior to check against our existing database of users/passwords and now we need to figure out how best to integrate the roles.  Does anyone have any points for the best/simplest solution this?  Am I going to have to override OnAuthorization or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement your own Role Provider, so this will be compatible with standard asp.net (mvc) validations.
[Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)